# Unexpected behaviour of linq group.by - closure?

Tags: linq, closures

I have a `List<Model>` *modelList* where `Model` contains a property *GuidProperty* of type `GUID?. All elements within this list are guaranteed not to have a null value as the list ist filtered using extension

```
modelList.Where(x=>x.GuidProperty.HasValue)
```

**Moreover each GUID is unique.**

Now by trying to iterate through this list `modelList` by

```
foreach (var model in modelList.GroupBy(x => x.GuidProperty.Value)){
        doSomething();
    }
```

I recognized that there are not as many groups as `modelList.Count` which does not makes sense to me. In my case one group was "missing".

Is this caused by the way I created this list `modelList`?:

```
//all guid are unique in the example
 List<Model> modelList = new List<Model>();

            using (var entities = _modelContext.EntitiesNoChanges)
            {
                modelList.AddRange(
                    entities.OrderProcessingItems.Where(x => x.GuidProperty.HasValue).ToList());


            }

//manually filled list of unique guids contained in modelList
List<Guid> guidList = new List<Guid>();

            foreach (var model in modelList)
            {
                // ReSharper disable once PossibleInvalidOperationException
                var guid = model.GuidProperty.Value;
                if (guidList.Contains(guid))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                guidList.Add(guid);
            }

// grouped list that should have n groups | n=modelList.Count
foreach (var model in modelList.GroupBy(x => x.GuidProperty.Value)){
        doSomething();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual problem:

```
-       guidList    Count = 4   System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Guid>
+       [0] {46952518-1529-4b0f-8123-6bad36057e84}  System.Guid
+       [1] {80395ccb-2307-4bea-b772-69b36ea8d663}  System.Guid
+       [2] {e1161daf-8c7b-4b31-a987-694e4563e0e6}  System.Guid
+       [3] {2c44861e-073b-42b2-8fbf-6ff0e1cc0b7b}  System.Guid
+       Raw View        

//this is the grouping for modelList - ignore namings...
-       offeringRateGroup   {System.Linq.Lookup<System.Guid, slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem>.Grouping}  System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Guid, slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem> {System.Linq.Lookup<System.Guid, slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem>.Grouping}
+       Key {46952518-1529-4b0f-8123-6bad36057e84}  System.Guid
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem>.Count    3   int
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem>.IsReadOnly   true    bool
        count   3   int
+       elements    {slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem[4]} slModel.Db.OrderProcessingItem[]
```

`guidList` is manually created and covers all models properies within the list.

**Update**
Order of code

Comment: you're right about the AddRange. yeah - I am sure that all guid are unique. I forgot to mention this sorry. Otherwise the assumption that the amount of gropus should be equal to modelList.Count would be incorrect.

Comment: You have duplicate GUIDs, that would explain this issue, otherwise your GroupBy doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: added debug information. as you can see my manual created guidList contains only unique GUIDs that are not fully reflected in the grouping.

Comment: also interesting: on mouseover on the group a 4th element "null" is displayed.

Comment: test how mny items are in the list after you filter it..  it seems you either have nulls or duplicate GUID. also - can you show the actual code in the order it is executed?

Comment: updated code snippet to actual order. notice that there are only unique guid in the list - as I said before.

Comment: Please line `continue;` to `throw new Exception("Duplicate GUID");` and run. What happens then?

Comment: Sorry I don't see the point of this. U clearly can see that there are at least 4 different GUIDs so there have to be also 4 groups.